# Is it possible to test a hybrid app with Xamarin UI.test c# and upload the same tests to cloud?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud

I have developed a Xamarin UI test for my hybrid app (not written with Xamarin). It is an android app and i have used Visual Studio2015 for the c# based test script development.

Now i need to upload the tests to the Xamarin Test cloud ? Is it possible ? If Yes then How? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since the mobile app was development outside of `Visual Studio` / `Xamarin Studio`, you need to submit the test and a release build of the `.apk` via the cmd-line tool (`test-cloud.exe`):

```
test-cloud.exe submit <PATH-TO-APK> <TEAM API KEY> --devices=<DEVICES> --assembly-dir=<PATH-TO-TEST-ASSEMBLY-DIR> --user=<EMAIL>
```

Consult the following link for details concerning app signing.

Ref: [Submitting_Android_Tests](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/submitting-tests-at-command-line/#Submitting_Android_Tests)